# Application.OnKey Cannot run Macro

Tags: excel, vba

So I have looked through many other posts about this very issue and they all say to put the sub in a standard module not in the worksheet, which I have, but I still get the error like others get.

```
Cannot run the macro "C:\myfile.xlsm'!SaveApp'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.
```

I have the SaveApp Sub in a Module like so:

```
Public Sub SaveApp()
 ' My code lives here
End Sub
```

I have the onkey code in

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
     With Application
         .OnKey "+^s", "SaveApp" 'Ctrl+Shift+S
     End With
End Sub
```

Seems very straight forward, so not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Have you enabled macros? File>Options>Trust Center>Trust Center Settings>Macro Settings>Enable Macros

Comment: Yes, I have many other macros in my file, and all of them working.

Comment: I've tried replicating the error using your Workbook_Open() code and implementing SaveApp with just a Msgbox in it ... and I don't get an error. So environmental differences aside, the only other difference would seem to be the code in the SaveApp routine. If you change that code to something simple and innocuous (e.g. msgbox or debug.print), does the error still occur?

Comment: Yes it still happens, but I might have found a different way to accomplish what I want. without having to use onkey